# Using jQuery each() function to calculate heights of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

Currently I'm using a function to calculate the height of certain divs within an element to enforce a jquery plugin called 'DotDotDot'. This works absolutely perfectly for a singular div. But what I'm trying to achieve is a series of divs doing this but currently it's not working out for me when using a .each() function, and it's breaking when it hits the second div. Would love any help on this, not the best at jQuery - fiddle below.

TL;DR

- Calculating heights of div inside container to ellipsis text with a jquery plugin called DotDotDot.
- Replicating for multiple divs using .each() function.
- Not working.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLp38687/6/)

[DotDotDot Plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#desc").each(function () {

    var imgheight = $(".image").height();
    var h2height = $("#desc h2").height();

    $("#desc").height(670 - imgheight - h2height - 30);

    $("#desc").dotdotdot({
        after: "a.readmore"
    });
});

});
```

Comment: You should include an excerpt of the markup.  Do the divs share a class?

Comment: as written, your .each() is pointless - it's going to loop on the results of `$('#desc')`, which only ever be ONE element (or none, if it doesn't exist). maybe you want `'#desc *'` to loop on all of #desc's children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly, ID attributes should be unique in the DOM.  You can't have #desc twice, so I've changed those to class.

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLp38687/7/

the jQuery:
With each you loop through the parent divs by selecting the example class.  In each iteration you select the children of the current example div with $(this).find(CHILD).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".example").each(function () {

        var imgheight = $(this).find(".image").height();
        var h2height = $(this).find(".desc h2").height();

        $(this).find(".desc").height(670 - imgheight - h2height - 30);

        $(this).find(".desc").dotdotdot({
            after: "a.readmore"
        });
    });

});
```

The updated markup (abridged a little)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="example">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/9ac8f53d4b3ec8d77865fd1b542a7b1f_xRgXa9UV_l.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
             <h2>This is a title of a post and it can span 2 lines</h2>

            <p>Lorem Ipsum isike Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/3156205047987_i80wZOig_l.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
             <h2>This is a title of a post and it can span 2 lines</h2>

            <p>Lorem Ipsum is set sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```